# Should Project Object Model contain separate test cases?

Tags: unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I couldn't find the answer I'm looking for so I decided to ask more experienced testers. I've implemented POM to my automation tests. I have A few different objects representing different sections of the website. I consider if I should create sepearate test case for each object ? I mean create separate .py files and import the libraries all over again or just import the objects to the one .py file which respresents the test ? Which approach will be more approporiate ?

Answer (score 0):

As every pattern, which should be a reusable solution - there is a specific context in play, one that makes it reasonable to utilize such pattern. I guess you've considered all **considerations** before jumping into POMs right away:

- Built Page Objects are very often hard to maintain and to use. Very well thought design is needed in grouping of elements into headers and footers, or identified widgets, there shouldn't just be a big list of stuff, names should be readable as well, enough to explain what they were for
- It might limit your design, e.g. you staring to ignore better abstractions.
- Not enough flexibility, especially for refactoring (both structure and implementation).
- POM is wrong by design, as it clearly violates [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle), by keeping elements map and the actions upon them.

As to

> if I should create sepearate test case for each object ? I mean create separate .py files and import the libraries all over again or just import the objects to the one .py file which respresents the test ?

Your [Test harness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_harness), should keep three separate concerns:

- test execution engine (core logic)
- the test scripts
- test data

So, simply put - don't mess scripts with POMs.

Here is a Github repo dedicated to [Automation in testing and design patterns](https://github.com/ekostadinov/luxoft-design-patterns-test-automation/blob/master/README.md). Fell free to use it!